# no sites loading in mozilla : Secure connection failed issue

Tags: 14.04, networking, firefox

I am not sure what has happened to my mozilla from last couple of days.

I am getting the below error.

> Secure Connection Failed
>
> An error occurred during a connection to www.google.com. security library failure. Error code: SEC_ERROR_LIBRARY_FAILURE

The solutions i tried:

1) Safe mode (Private window) - Same issue
2) Reinstalled - Same issue.

Please help.

Comment: Check if these steps resolves the issue.

(1) Type About:Config in the Address Bar and press Enter.

(2) “This Might be your warranty!” warning will be display, click on I’ll be careful, I Promise button.

(3) Type security.ssl.enable_ocsp_stapling in search box.

(4) The value field is true, double click on it to make the it false.

(5) Now try to connect your website again

Answer (score 0):

I did the steps as mentioned in my comment above (i.e. in about:config, I made " security.ssl.enable_ocsp_stapling " to false. But this did not resolve the issue in my machine (Ubuntu 15.10 and firefox 47.0).

So then, from the help menu in Firefox, I just did "Restart with Add ons Disabled." and now I got back to a normal functioning Firefox.

If the above does not work for you below are some pages that may be of help

1. https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1081813
2. https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1073420
3. https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1081813